# Python – RabbitMQ/Pika basic manager in OOP style

Tags: python, object-oriented, rabbitmq

I created some classes for easier management of RabbitMQ and to practice OOP in Python.

I would care about a few issues and any code advice would be appreciated :)

1. is it a good practice to use the isinstance function in the constructor?
2. does using the context manager in these cases close the channel? It seems to me that any use of, for example, the "send()" function opens the channel and closes it.
3. not sure if I shouldn't close the connection after the use of each instance is complete.

````
import pika
import colorlog
import logging
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(
    colorlog.ColoredFormatter(
        "\033[35m| \033[0m\033[32mRabbitMQ-\033[0m%(log_color)s%(levelname)-8s%(reset)s %(blue)s%(message)s",
        log_colors={
            "DEBUG": "cyan",
            "INFO": "green",
            "WARNING": "yellow",
            "ERROR": "red",
            "CRITICAL": "red,bg_white",
        },
    )
)

logger = colorlog.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class Exchange(Enum):
    DEFAULT = ""
    DIRECT = "direct"
    TOPIC = "topic"
    FANOUT = "fanout"


@dataclass
class RabbitDataConnection:
    username: str
    password: str
    host: str = "localhost"


@dataclass
class RabbitDataProducer:
    exchange: Exchange
    routing_key: str
    body: str


@dataclass
class RabbitDataExchange:
    exchange: str
    exchange_type: Exchange
    queue: str
    routing_key: str
    durable: bool = True


@dataclass
class RabbitDataQueue:
    queue: str
    durable: bool = True


@dataclass
class RabbitDataConsumer:
    queue: str
    auto_ack: bool


class RabbitConnection:
    def __init__(
        self,
        creds: RabbitDataConnection,
    ):
        assert isinstance(creds, RabbitDataConnection)
        self.creds = creds

    def _get_connection(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.creds.username, self.creds.password)
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=self.creds.host, credentials=credentials
        )
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        logger.info(f"Connecting to {self.creds.host} as {self.creds.username}")
        return connection.channel()


class RabbitProducer(RabbitConnection):
    def __init__(
        self,
        creds: RabbitDataConnection,
        producer: RabbitDataProducer,
    ):
        assert isinstance(producer, RabbitDataProducer)
        super().__init__(creds)
        self.producer = producer

    def send(self):
        with self._get_connection() as channel:
            channel.basic_publish(
                exchange=self.producer.exchange,
                routing_key=self.producer.routing_key,
                body=self.producer.body,
                properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                    delivery_mode=pika.spec.PERSISTENT_DELIVERY_MODE
                ),
            )
            logger.info(f"Sent {self.producer.body} as {self.producer.exchange}")


class RabbitExchange(RabbitConnection):
    def __init__(
        self,
        creds: RabbitDataConnection,
        exchange: RabbitDataExchange,
    ):
        assert isinstance(exchange, RabbitDataExchange)
        super().__init__(creds)
        self.exchange = exchange

    def create_binding_key(self):
        with self._get_connection() as channel:
            channel.queue_bind(
                exchange=self.exchange.exchange,
                queue=self.exchange.queue,
                routing_key=self.exchange.routing_key,
            )
            logger.info(
                f"Exchange {self.exchange.exchange} has been connected with {self.exchange.queue} by routing key {self.exchange.routing_key}"
            )

    def create_exchange(self):
        with self._get_connection() as channel:
            channel.exchange_declare(
                exchange=self.exchange.exchange,
                exchange_type=self.exchange.exchange_type,
                durable=self.exchange.durable,
            )
            logger.info(
                f"Exchange {self.exchange.exchange} - {self.exchange.exchange_type} has been created"
            )


class RabbitQueue(RabbitConnection):
    def __init__(self, creds: RabbitDataConnection, queue: RabbitDataQueue):
        assert isinstance(queue, RabbitDataQueue)
        super().__init__(creds)
        self.queue = queue

    def create_queue(self):
        with self._get_connection() as channel:
            channel.queue_declare(
                queue=self.queue.queue,
                durable=self.queue.durable,
            )
            logger.info(f"Queue {self.queue.queue} has been created")


class RabbitConsumer(RabbitConnection):
    def __init__(self, creds: RabbitDataConnection, consumer: RabbitDataConsumer):
        assert isinstance(consumer, RabbitDataConsumer)
        super().__init__(creds)
        self.consumer = consumer

    def consume_messages(self):
        with self._get_connection() as channel:
            channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
            method, properties, body = channel.basic_get(
                queue=self.consumer.queue,
                auto_ack=self.consumer.auto_ack,
            )
            logger.info("Messages was consumed")
            return body

    def stop_consuming(self):
        with self._get_connection() as channel:
            channel.stop_consuming()
            logger.info("Consuming messages has been stopped")
```
````